# Using offset.left and width() in backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have one backbone view (view 1) that renders another (view 2). View 1 also adds a click event to category links in view 1 that triggers an event in view 2 (`view2.trigger("elementAdded")`). The event function in view 2 checks for the width and offset left of image elements to display them in a carousel. View 1 passes the image links to view 2, which displays them in a carousel. I have trouble retrieving the width and offset left (left position on the page) of these images in view 2 event function because they have not yet been added to the DOM (using `$('.image').offset().left` and `$('.image').width()` gives me the wrong information sometimes). How do you handle situations like that when you're using Backbone to render HTML elements? How can I trigger the event once I know that the elements have been added to the DOM? How can I make sure the elements were added to the DOM so that I get the right info?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably get the width before it's in the DOM. It may be affected by CSS, etc. that aren't applied until the element is in the DOM.